# f continuous in almost all [0,1]×[0,1] and f does not coincide in almost all with any continuous function

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis, continuity, lebesgue-measure

I'm working on a problem I'm stagnant with. A few hours ago, with some help, I solved a similar problem but quite different. That problem was about giving functions f,g so that f is continuous in [0,1] x [0,1] and in almost all equal to g while g is not continuous in any point, I took f = 0 and g as the characteristic function of Q×Q on [0,1]×[0,1].

"Give a function f so that f is continuous in almost all [0,1]×[0,1] and f does not coincide in almost all with any continuous function"

I thought about taking f as the inverse of the characteristic function of QxQ on [0,1]×[0,1], it is continuous in almost all [0,1]×[0,1] but coincide in almost all with g = 1, for example. So that attempt is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is written in a confusing way, but here's how I'm interpreting the quantifiers:

> Give a function $f$ such that $f$ is continuous at almost all points in $[0,1]\times [0,1]$, but there is no continuous function $g$ such that $f = g$ almost everywhere.

A simple example:
$$
f(x,y) = \begin{cases}
1 & x \geq 1/2, \\ 
0 & x < 1/2.
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: That's right, that is my question, but how can I be sure that doesn't exist g such that f=g? (f is the function you wrote)

Comment: @WindyH A hint: if $g$ is continuous, then there must exist a non-empty *open set* on which $f \neq g$.